# How do I set the default screen sharing window/tab in Firefox 71

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I'm prototyping a quick dial web interface in Firefox 71 and I've changed the `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to `true` in `about:config` so that I don't have to deal with the pop-up permissions dialog while I'm testing.

But when it comes to screen sharing, is there a way that I can suppress the dialog by setting the default shared window/screen or tab?

Answer (score 1):

> ⚠️ Setting `media.navigator.permission.disabled` in about:config is dangerous: It turns off Firefox's permission prompts, letting any web site access your camera, microphone or capture your screen!

The screen-sharing prompt should [already be suppressed](https://jan-ivar.github.io/dummy/gdm.html) if you have that pref set, in which case it defaults to sharing the entire desktop. This is [used](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/web-platform/meta/screen-capture/__dir__.ini) in [tests](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/c79fc6e32a5b561205a71fcfef9112d34b4037ae/testing/web-platform/tests/screen-capture/getdisplaymedia.https.html#48), and [should not be used](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/share-browser-windows-entire-screen-sites-trust/) outside tests!

As for changing the default to something else, `getDisplayMedia` has no such feature. An older non-standard API had that, but is [being removed soon](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1557174).